# Checking Current Kernel for automated driver compiling

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, kernel

I just bought a new notebook and set it up with Arch Linux.
After the setup, I noticed that the Wi-Fi Chip isn't supported for Linux. (yet)

But I found the required driver for it.

The problem is, whenever a Kernel Update gets released, I have to compile the driver again.
Now, I want to automate this action.

My goal is to write a script which tests every boot, if a new kernel is installed and I wrote following for now.

```
#!/bin/bash
// Ignore the point please

CURRENTKERNEL="$(uname -r)"
INSTALLEDKERNEL="$(ls -l /lib/modules | grep $CURRENTKERNEL)"

if [[ $CURRENTKERNEL != $INSTALLEDKERNEL ]]; then   
    echo "Kernel is not the same"
else
    echo "Kernel is the same"
fi
```

The problem about this code is, that he checks the kernel version and it will always be true, because `uname -r` prints out the currently installed kernel and in `/lib/modules` the folder with the exact same name is present.

I  searched the web, and even StackOverflow, but I found nothing helpful.

I would appreciate any kind of tip.

Comment: Wouldn't a `pacman` hook be more suitable? A hook is script that is triggered before or after specific `pacman` operations. In your case that trigger would be *"kernel updated"*.

Comment: on redhat they were using dkms for such problems, at a time...

Comment: that said you may use `modinfo` on your custom built module to check if the version it was compiled for matches the current kernel

Comment: @Socowi Sounds very interesting. I have already found a tutorial of manjaro. I will try it out.